# What does the "optimize" button do?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-unchained-x

Kingdom Hearts Unchained X recently added an "optimize" button the pre-quest Keyblade select screen. When this button is clicked, it moves medals from your medal list into your Keyblade, but does not explain how it chose the medals it chose. The only thing that I've been able to find is that it adheres to the medal requirements for the selected proud mode quest.

[image: Optimize button example]

So how does it go about choosing the medals that it chooses to insert into the Keyblade?

Answer (score -3):

According to [this Tips & Tricks article](https://www.imore.com/kingdom-hearts-game-guide-defeat-heartless-one-blow):

> The easiest way to level up a medal is to use the Optimize button. It will sort the available medals into their appropriate slot and all you have to do is tap the Level Up button.
>
> Check between each level that you play to see if you can level up any medals (across all of your Keyblades).

Comment: This explains what the optimize function can be used for, not what it does. The question was, how does the game choose which medals should be inserted into the Keyblade?

Comment: Hi Pown, it seems you've copied your entire answer from another source. I've edited in the correct source for you this time. Please have a look at our [rules on plagiarism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and in future, remember to state clearly where you got any information when posting :-)